# How do Apps know that a license was bought specifically for that (does it matter)?

Tags: appexchange, licenses, userlicense

So my organisation purchased x amount of RemedyForce licenses. When I log into Salesforce I can view these licenses as Salesforce Platform licenses as expected.  I can also view the x number of additional RemedyForce Self Service Licenses that come with the product.  That's fine, except as these only display as Salesforce Platform Licenses and we have x number of  these already they simply display as 1 total/used for that license type.

I would like to know how RemedyForce knows that the Platform license is a license for RemedyForce?  Does it know, or can any Platform license work?

Hope that makes sense, I am just trying to understand how the link between our license invoice -> salesforce -> BMC works as on the cover in Salesforce the Platform License's althought bought via Salesforce for different things all appear as 1 total.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

When you look at an individual user record there should be a bmc remedyforce section and within this there should be some tick boxes for "Assign Remedyforce License" and "ServiceDesk Staff" i believe it is these tick boxes that BMC uses to know how many licenses you are using.

Comment: I can't see this in sandbox, I presume when it is installed in production it is slightly different.  Essentially is there a difference between the Platform licenses listed under Company Information?  Could we utilise these as additional RemedyForce users without going to the partner for more licenses?